# Image Resizer in .Net Core

Tags: imageresizer

Can the people at Imazen tell us that although the ImageResizing library does not support .NET core, if we add the System.Drawing part of .NET in our MVC Core application, will it then work for now. We know that they are working on ImageFlow - but till that comes out would this be an option?

P.S. Any idea when ImageFlow will be released?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Imageflow bindings for .NET Core have been out for 8 months. I would suggest this as better option.

https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet

Comment: The link is dead. Could you try again please. Thanks

Comment: I found it at https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet. Are there any documentation of how to use it. Thanks